# Add templates to TeXworks

Tags: miktex, templates, texworks

Using TeXworks 0.4.3 r.857 (MiKTeX 2.9) on Windows 7 I am trying to add an arbitrary folder containing a template so that it can be seen from TeXworks's `New from Template...` option. I can't figure out how to inform TeXworks as to where it should look.

I understand I can add templates next to the built in ones that appear under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.4\templates`. There are multiple files that go with this template, including a .sty class that I would like to keep in one place accessible to the user (probably through a SVN repo), so I don't like the idea of putting the templates in that hidden directory. I can tell MiKTeX to use an arbitrary root for packages, and would like to do the same for TeXworks and templates.

Answer (score 2):

Install a second version of TeXworks from http://www.tug.org/texworks/
This version won't interfere with the native version installed by MiKTeX. 
Templates of this version are placed in `MyName\TeXworks\templates` where `MyName` is your username under Windows.
Sorry, I couldn't find anything better...

Answer (score 1):

Simply place a link to your template directory into `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.4\templates`

Answer (score 1):

The first part you outlined yourself, navigate to C:\Users\\TeXworks\templates\. Restart TeXworks and it will appear in the "New File from Template" window. You'll have to install the .sty file to a separate folder.

For the .sty file: navigate to C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex. Copy the .sty file to a new folder. You should now be able to access the style file when you compile the template.