# How to creat a quick start which includes some particular packages?

Tags: automation

Whenever I begin a document in latex, I have to add a lot of necessary packages such as packages about Tikz or language packages. My quesion is how to creat a quick start which includes some particular packages ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{vntex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,tkz-linknodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[width=0.00cm, height=0.00cm, left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Text...Text
\end{document}
```

`

Comment: This question pops up often and the common advice is: every individual document needs an individual preamble. Quick start not recommended.

Comment: You can define templates in most editors though. Or simply copy your template file.

Comment: In TeXworks you can define so-called templates where you can load a few packages and set up some definitions. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66477/35864

Comment: Elegant: Make your own class (`myclass.cls`). Flexible: Make your own pakage (`mypackage.sty`) . Quick and dirty, but also work:  save your preamble to `mypreamble.tex`  and load with `\input{mypreamble}`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this: create a base file.

I have a folder `Tex` where all my files are in. I then have the `_Base` folder where I have a `Base.tex` file in it. There, I've defined all basic infos such as header etc. such that they look the same in every document plus environments / commands I reuse. You can then use this `Base.tex` file with `\input{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\input{../_Base/Base.tex}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

What my base document looks like (partly):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft,
    graphicx,
    hyperref,
    calc,
    listings,
    longtable
}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,headheight=27pt]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Colours
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{PatheYellow}{HTML}{FFC426}
\definecolor{PatheSilver}{HTML}{A7A9AC}
\definecolor{PatheGrey}{HTML}{707174}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}
\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to write your own custom package (named `customizeme` for example), guidelines are here : https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Writing_your_own_package

Then once it's installed you'll juste have to do the old `\usepackage{customizeme}` and that'll do the trick.

Or if you want you can also write you're very own style, which is more work but also more glory ^^